# Change value of a cell based on a drop menu of values on a different sheet for invoice

Tags: google-sheets

I have seen this question in similar posts, but I can't get it to work. When I select the product in the drop down in column B, I want it to populate the unit price in column F. If no selection in column B, I want column F to be blank.

Here is the link to the sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NXcbXUUaqCm6gIbXeD4vuAr_TBS0X-DWs6JMv2hASg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webappss.se]. While a link to an external resource might be helpful questions should be self-constained, in other words please add more details about what you tried directly into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iferror()` and the correct `search_key` range reference, like this:

`=iferror( vlookup(B19, Data!A$2:B, columns(Data!A$2:B), false) )`